# When i am trying to use @ResController in my maven project it showing error " RestController can not be resolved to a type".Help me to resolve this

Tags: java, api, rest, maven, web-services

**pom.xml**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
 

com.java
restful-web-service
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
restful-web-service
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**Here my simple code to create Rest api**

```
package com.java.restfulwebservice;

@RestController
public class HelloworldController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you give import import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

Comment: I thought that it will import automatically.Now i import it and it works.Thank You

Comment: Good it helped you . I answered it. Could you please help upvoting and accepting it for bettter visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please import the RestController like below :

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```